# About giving differences to one chapter

Tags: changes

i have the following question.

Suppose i have a main file and separate chapters. Then all is compile in a pdf file (for example).

The question is how to change features of only one chapter.

For example:

```
\documentclass[12pt,twoside]{report}

\title{\vspace{-4.0cm}Study}}

\begin{document}

\maketitle


\tableofcontents

\chapter{Introduction}
\input{chapte/intro}

\chapter{State}
\input{chapte/state}



\end{document}
```

And then i want to change the font type only in one of the chapters, how can i do it?

Should i use some package in the chapter i want to change?

Comment: font changes just obey normal tex groups so you can put `{\itshape \input{....}}` and the chapter will be in italic, if that's what you want.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle So all features of a chapter are indicated in "main file".tex?

Comment: you can split file up into separate files to be input by chapter or section or every paragraph but that's just for your convenience while editing:  tex doesn't care, the `\input` text is just treated as if it was copied in at that point (not quite true but near enough).

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Ok. So if i understand you, changes can be made directly in the file but usually is it not necessary..because i can change it in main file

Comment: The difference is visible only to your eye, you see the command either n the main file, or the `\input`ed file. But for TeX, it is exactly the same.

Comment: Looking at your questions, i recommend to [read an introduction to LaTeX](http://www.dickimaw-books.com/latex/novices/index.html) (<- Link to a free ebook).

Comment: @Johannes_B Yes, today i understand the way it works. Anyway, i need to read an introduction, i know, but i prefer first a bit of "do what i can" without reading, and then go through a text. Thank you.